# How to use python functions in conf.py file in Sphinx

Tags: python, import, python-sphinx

I've written a little python function, called myFunction, stored in function.py that I'd like to call within a conf.py file. The function works fine when called from a test python file, so I appear to have a problem importing modules in this file specifically.

The setup is like this:

DocumentSourceFolder/sourcefile.txt

DocumentSourceFolder/conf.py

DocumentSourceFolder/function.py

Within conf.py I have added the following:

`import function`

`variable = function.myFunction()`

(where variable is something that already exists within the conf.py file).

When running sphinx on this document, however, I receive the error:

`ImportError: No module named function`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Sphinx is a bit picky with importing python modules in the conf.py file. To avoid errors you need to do 2 steps:

1)
Add to you conf.py file

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.relpath('relative/path/to/folder/containing/module'))
```

This means sphinx now looks here for extension modules. Then you have to add the module name to the `extensions = [...]` list.

2)
Add to you module the following:

```
def setup(app):
    return
```

This 'setup() function' is required for sphinx to accept that your module is indeed an extension module.

Done!

Comment: You can import any module you like in conf.py (as long as it's in `sys.path`). It does not have to be an extension module with a `setup()` function.

Comment: Trying it without the setup() function results in an error when running Sphinx

Comment: If you just want to import a module from conf.py, make sure it can be found via `sys.path`. If the module is supposed to be a Sphinx extension module, you must also add it to the extensions configuration variable and include a `setup()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from function import function
```

.

With:

```
import function
```

Python tries to import a module; which your file obviously isn't.
See sections from the http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That only gave the same error as before. The solution was actually with sphinx.

Comment: I've added my solution below.

Comment: "*Python tries to import a module; which your file obviously isn't*"? Why do you say that? Of course it is a module. [A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules).